# Choropleth map plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, geospatial, choropleth

I have a geo json file that gives data about political districts in PA (state in USA):
api='https://www.redistricting.state.pa.us/Resources/GISData/Districts/Legislative/House/2021-Final/JSON/2022%20LRC-House-Final.json'

I have dataset that looks smth like this:

```
|   |District|Total Population|...|
|---|--------|----------------|---|
|0  |1       |35000           |...|
|1  |2       |67800           |...|
|2  |3       |93300           |...|
|...|...     |...             |...|
```

Json file and dataset can be connected by 'District' variable in both (df['District'] in dataset, and ['properties']['District'] in json)

I need to produce map that draws polygons of districts in PA based on coordinates given in json file in ['geometry'], and shows total population of those districts from the data given in df

Here is what I tried:

```
with urlopen(api) as response:
    geo = json.load(response) 
    
districts_geo=[]

for district in geo['features']:
    district_no=district['properties']['District']
    geometry=district['geometry']
    districts_geo.append({
        'type':'Feature',
        'geometry':geometry,
        'id':district_no
    })
    
districts_geo_ok={'type':'FeatureCollection','features':districts_geo}   

fig=px.choropleth(df, geojson=districts_geo_ok, scope='usa' ,locations='District', color='Total population')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

The problem is I am getting this wrong output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running `px.choropleth()` with the geojson presented and the color bar shows up but the map does not. It is true that there may be an issue with the geojson, but I decided that it would be too difficult to lead it to the correct form, so I used a different map.
`px.choropleth_mapbox()` was able to handle this issue. You are the one who should verify that the output fill area matches.

```
from urllib import request
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

api='https://www.redistricting.state.pa.us/Resources/GISData/Districts/Legislative/House/2021-Final/JSON/2022%20LRC-House-Final.json'

with request.urlopen(api) as f:
    geo = json.load(f)

district = []
for d in range(len(geo['features'])):
    dis = geo['features'][d]['properties']['District']
    district.append(dis)

df = pd.DataFrame({'District': district, 'Total Population': np.random.randint(100, 10000, len(geo['features']))})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, 
                           geojson=geo,
                           locations='District',
                           color='Total Population',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 10000),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=6,
                           center={"lat": 41.0, "lon": -78.0},
                           opacity=0.3,
                           labels={'Total Population':'Population'}
                          )

fig.update_layout(autosize=False, height=600, width=1000, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]